# Page listing post_type pagination not working

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

I created a page template for join all posts from a specific post_type in one page, everything is working except the pagination. It show the right number of posts for page but, in this case, I have 8 posts and it only show 5. I did some changes but without success. Any ideas?

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: News
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- begin colLeft -->

<div class="container">
        <main id="main" class="container" role="main">


            <?php 
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                query_posts(array('paged' => get_query_var('paged'), 'posts_per_page'=>5, 'post_type'=>'our-work', 'order' => 'ASC'))
            ?>

            <br><br><br>

            <!--header-->
            <div class="page-header">
                <img src="www.wtk.com/img/3428245.png">
            </div>


            <div class="inform">
                Display text here
            </div> 

            <br>

            <div>
                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="news-title">
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            </div>

            <div class="news-box">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more →</a>
            </div>

            <br><br>


            <?php endwhile;?>

            <?php if (function_exists("emm_paginate")) {
                emm_paginate();
            } ?>

            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

            <?php else : ?>
                <p><?php _e('Not found'); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>

</div>

<!-- end colleft -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: As an aside, avoid using `query_posts()`. Use the `WP_Query` class instead.

Answer (score 0):

I can see in your code you have `'posts_per_page' => 5`. That would explain why you are seeing only 5 posts on the page.

Comment: Yes, but with the pagination function should exist a page number at the content footer so I could click on it and it would see the rest of them. But this is not happening.